# Android EditText pre filled text

Tags: android, android-layout

working on an application
i need to take an EditText.
but i need as in the phone :-

**The EditText already contains blurred text such as "Your Name" when you start typing the text vanishes and you text is shown. I hope you've seen this effect/property..**
I'm not getting what this property is called to be searched on google...

Comment: However you knew how to ask. At least this question (with the answer of course) helped me too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint

Answer (score 3):

Use the following in your layout.xml file of edittext:

```
  android:hint="Here your hint text"
```